# Запись массива в строку и отдача файла на скачку Php

Tags: php

пытаюсь разобраться с простой задачей. Нужно при обращение к урлу перебрать данные, получив на выходе строку, записать в файл и отдать на скачивание.
Массив формируется из запроса к базе, потом перебирается. В итоге получается такая структура

```
foreach ($allRes as $row){
    foreach ($row as $k => $v){
        if($k != 'section_id')
        {

            $str.= $v . $col_delimiter. '  -  ' . $count;
        }
    }
    $count++;
    $str .= $row_delimiter;
}
```

В итоге получается строка с переносами

Сделал так, всё работает, но не все строки попадают в скаченный файл

```
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="str.txt"');
 header('Content-Type: text/plain'); 
 header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($str));
 header('Connection: close');
 echo $str;
```

Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Что такое `$str`, как формируется это значение? Также, при работе с данными в кодировке например utf-8 `strlen` выдаст неверное значение.

Comment: Во время перебора массива в str записываю строки

`foreach ($allRes as $row){
    foreach ($row as $k => $v){
        if($k != 'section_id')
        {

         $resSrt .= $v . $col_delimiter. '  -  ' . $count;
        }
    }
    $count++;
 $str.= $row_delimiter;
 
}`
`mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`
`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ads.txt"');
header('Content-Type: text/plain'); 
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($str));
header('Connection: close');
echo $str;`

Код без получения данных.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно не правильно длину строки посчитала. Хотя пробовал и `mb_strlen` прибавило только 100, но всё-равно не всё.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете не указывать `Content-Length` если укажете заголовок `Content-Transfer-Encoding`

> A sender **MUST NOT** send a Content-Length header field in any message
> that contains a Transfer-Encoding header field. [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2)

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain';
header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename="str.txt"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

// If you're serving to IE, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: ' . (new \DateTime('now'))->format('r'));
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
echo $str;
```